# Fetching a contact from Contacts Framework is not working iOS 13

Tags: swift, ios13, ios12, cncontact, cncontactstore

In my application I create a CNContact and save to the contacts store, I also save the contact's *identifier*. In another section of the app I use the *identifier* to fetch that contact but is not working in iOS 13. (**This does works on iOS 12**)

**Note:** I am aware of the contact note key permission on iOS 13, but I am not fetching that field.

Here is how I create the contact:

```
func createPlaceholderContactFor(telephoneNumber: String) {
    guard
        placeholderContactIdentifier == nil,
        CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .authorized
    else {
        return
    }

    // Creating a mutable object to add to the contact
    let contact = CNMutableContact()
    contact.imageData = UIImage(named: "MainIcon")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
    contact.givenName = placeholderDefaultName
    contact.familyName = ""
    contact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(
        label:CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone,
        value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:telephoneNumber))]

    // Saving the newly created contact
    let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
    saveRequest.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier:nil)

    do {
        let store = CNContactStore()
        try store.execute(saveRequest)

        if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactIdentifierKey) {
            print(contact.identifier) //this is printed on console and contact appears on phone app.
            placeholderContactIdentifier = contact.identifier
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

This is how I fetch the contact:

```
private func placeholderContact() -> CNContact? {
    guard
        let identifier = placeholderContactIdentifier,
        CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .authorized
        else { return nil }

    let predicate: NSPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(withIdentifiers: [identifier])

    let keysToFetch = [
        CNContactIdentifierKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
        CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
        CNContactFamilyNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor
    ]

    do {
        let store = CNContactStore()

        let contacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
        return contacts.first
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

        return nil
    }
}
```

I also tried using `let contact = try store.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: identifier, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)` instead of `let contacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)` but this throws an error.

Comment: What is the output of the `print(error.localizedDescription)` call? Where does the code stop if you set an exception breakpoint in the debugger?

Comment: @GeneZ.Ragan when I call `store.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: keysToFech:)` the error is: `Updated Record Does Not Exist`